# uploading eclipse project into Github account first time

Tags: eclipse, github

See I am doing it for the first time meaning the project was never added to GitHub repository... so when I right click the project->Team->Commit .. I see files under Unstaged Section and cant commit as I see that message "There are no staged files" so does this mean I have to do this step before Right click the project->Team->Add to Index?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to stage files before you can commit them. This is just the normal git workflow, regardless if you're using the git CLI or eGit.

https://wiki.eclipse.org/WTP_Git_Migration_Home lists some learning materials you can use, and eGit itself has a good user guide at https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide .

Comment: So what is exact step do I first Right click the project->Team->Add to Index? or Should I go to right click the project->Team->Commit and drag the files from unstaged section to staged section and click Commit button? I am using GIT Plugin in Eclipse

Comment: The Eclipse UI is not hiding git's complexity, and it expects you know the concepts and jargon specific to git so it can use them throughout the UI. What you've said sounds like it would work, but knowing how to use git will be valuable to you later on.

Comment: thank you for the response. I wanted to know the difference see when i do Add to index and than to go to perform Commit all the unstaged files moves to staged section ..why ? Whats difference between me manually dragging them to staged section and than clicking commit? Are both same way ?

Comment: You only commit what you stage by adding to the index. When and how you do that doesn't really matter.

Comment: so it means no need to add to index..i can straight forward drag files from unstaged section to staged section and click commit. Correct